# bash, show full path, exclude filename

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Im trying to make a print recursivelly the whole path of files, but exclude the files, as little i know, using `find /this/path/ -type f` will print

```
/this/path/file1
/this/path/file2
/this/path/also/file3
/this/path/also/this/file4
```

adding `| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/"} ; { print $NF}'` will print

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

What i need is some way to print the whole path of every file, but without the actual file, something like this:

```
/this/path/
/this/path/
/this/path/also/
/this/path/also/this/
```

Comment: `basename /this/path/file1 will output `file`,  `dirname /this/path/file1` will output `/this/path`

Comment: don't you want to eliminate duplicate paths?

Comment: no, i need the duplicated paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of `find` supports `-printf`, it makes it very easy to get the dirname:

```
$ find /this/path/ -type f -printf '%h\n'
/this/path
/this/path
/this/path/also
/this/path/also/this
```

As well, you can simplify getting the basename with the same technique:

```
$ find /this/path/ -type f -printf '%f\n'
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Details from [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
%f
File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element). 
...
%h
Leading directories of file's name (all but the last element). If the file name contains
no slashes (since it is in the current directory) the %h specifier expands to ".".
```

Comment: But note that `-printf` is not standard, and may not be available in your implementation of `find`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, it does works with my version

Answer (score 3):

There should be available commands `basename` and `dirname`:

```
find -type f -exec dirname {} \;
```

or

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dirname
```